# Что произойдёт в результате выполнения данной команды

Tags: linux, ssh, unix

Желательно описать каждую команду, т.к. столкнулся с таким впервые

```
ssh wolf find /forest/test/ -regex 0-9 .mp4 -mmin +3 -ls
```

Comment: Заголовок вопроса лучше переписать, а то здесь уже были подобные темы вопросов и внутри они были не очень приятны. Могут случайно забанить:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как всегда, лучше разбить на куски и так разбирать

```
ssh wolf
```

команду ниже выполнить на компьютере, к которому подключаемся по ssh с именем wolf

```
find
```

команда искать

```
/forest/test/
```

в этом каталоге

```
-regex 0-9 .mp4
```

регулярка для имени. Тут чуть сложнее, но подозреваю, что потерялись кавычки

```
-mmin +3
```

файлы были модифицированы 3 минуты назад или более

```
-ls
```

их список распечатать (как будто это сделала команда ls).

как уточнили в коментариях, регулярка такая `.*/[0-9]+\.mp4'`. Это будет "файлы, которые имеют расширение mp4 и в конце цифры. То есть, "test123.mp4" - подходит. "data.mp4" - нет.

Comment: ssh wolf "find /forest/test/* -regex '.*/[0-9]+\.mp4' -mmin +3 -ls"
вот фулл с нормальной регуляркой

Comment: Хотя бы одна цифра перед точкой, точнее. Необязательно в конце должны быть цифры, могут быть и исключительно цифры

Comment: я написал "в конце цифры". я думаю, это очевидно, что там должна быть хотя бы одна цифра.

Comment: Поправка: файлы были модифицированы _три и более_ минуты назад.

Comment: спс, поправил..